# How to remove space from ArrayList at beginning of the elements in Android

Tags: android, arrays, arraylist, removing-whitespace

I want to remove space in beginning o Arraylist elements.
Example: **[Barcelona, Brugge, Chicago, Hong Kong, Los Angeles]**

Remove space from the beginning of Elements.

[Barcelona, Brugge, Chicago, Hong Kong, Los Angeles]

Comment: You want to remove white space between the city's name? Are those String?

Comment: not between cities name. i want to remove before cities name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I don't know why you should care about those spaces, as an ArrayList stores the objects and does not generate a list like that.

If that is a parsed String, than you can go with this:

```
String s = "[Barcelona, Brugge, Chicago, Hong Kong, Los Angeles]";
s.replace(", ", ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String str = yourArrayList.toString();
str.replace(", ",",");
```